# Inequality: $\frac{a+b+c}{2} \geq \frac{ab}{a+b} + \frac{bc}{b+c} + \frac{ca}{c+a}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

I am asking this question on behalf of another student, who sought my help through a school mentoring scheme, and claims that the question is similar to that found in Question $1$ of the British Maths Olympiad.

Prove that for all positive real numbers $a, b, c$:

a) $(a+b)^2 \geq 4ab$

b) $\frac{a+b+c}{2} \geq \frac{ab}{a+b} + \frac{bc}{b+c} + \frac{ca}{c+a}$

The person mentioned solved a) easily but struggled with b). To solve b), the person had attempted the following:

"...putting the right hand side as a single fraction and then cross multiplying as well as cancelling terms. But it turns out to be a repeated process which makes the original question even more complicated."

[image]

Comment: Add your own work, please. What did you try?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @Wolgwang Thanks, I am in the process of adding what I've done so far

Comment: OP it's best you type out your attempt using MathJax, instead of adding pictures. Thanks for adding context, though.

Comment: Why did you include part 1?

Comment: Just to include the full context of the question - it's probably meant to help in solving part b)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From AM-HM inequality, we have-
$$\frac {a+b}{2}\geq \frac {2ab}{a+b}$$
Similarly write the inequality for $\{b,c\}$ and $\{c,a\}$, and add. You obtain:
$$\frac {a+b+c}{2}\geq \frac {ab}{a+b}+\frac {bc}{b+c}+\frac {ac}{a+c}$$ which is the required result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 3):

Looking at part a), I think the intention of part b) is

\begin{eqnarray*}\frac{ab}{a+b} + \frac{bc}{b+c} + \frac{ca}{c+a}
& \stackrel{a)}{\leq} & \frac{(a+b)^2}{4(a+b)} +\frac{(b+c)^2}{4(b+c)} + \frac{(a+c)^2}{4(a+c)} \\
& = & \frac 14(a+b + b+c + a+c) \\
& = & \frac{a+b+c}{2}
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\dfrac{ab}{a+b}=\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}}$. If we did not have $\dfrac{1}{b}$, then the term would be exactly $a$. However, you are adding $\dfrac{1}{b}$ to the denominator, which is positive because $b$ is positive. Therefore $a\geq \dfrac{ab}{a+b}$. You can apply the same argument to the other three terms to get the inequality you want.

Comment: Your argument applies well to the initial version of the inequality, but appears to not work properly for the updated question.  Would you mind revisiting?

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure how to extend my argument to apply to the updated question. I thought of a different argument, which is showing that $\dfrac{ab}{a+b}$ has a maximum when $b=a$ at $\dfrac{a}{2}$ using derivatives. But I think the solution given by @Ritam_Dasgupta is already good enough :)